# Why is the output of y , 0.000?

Tags: c, initialization, type-conversion, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    float y = x>10;
    printf("y is %f",y);
}
```

also if `x<10` the output is 1.0000?

*My Attempt*

So x is 3 and `x<10` being true returns 1.00 and `x>10` being false return 0.00 but still why is float acting like bool. Why is y not returning some garbage value?

Comment: "Why is y not returning some garbage value?" - Why should it? And please provide a refeerence to the standard defining "garbage value". What is that?

Comment: @UnholySheep: C very well has a **bool**ean type: `_Bool` and provides a header defining the macro `bool`.

Comment: Certainly the output was `"1.000000"` and not `"1.0000"`.  True transcription is often important in solving issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.107) **The result has
>   type int**

Assigning an integer value to an object of type float is a well defined operation.

In fact you can consider this code snippet

```
int x = 3;
float y = x>10;
```

like

```
int temporary = 0; // x > 10
float y = temporary;
```